# Would this authentication on a Diffie-Hellmann-key-exchanged channel work?

Tags: hash, diffie-hellman, authentication, authenticated-encryption, otr

Before I ask my question, let me say that I don't know the math behind OTR, so I don't know if the process of authentication in OTR is any similar to this.

---

- Alice and Bob have exchanged keys using Diffie-Hellman key exchange
- There's a man-in-the-middle - Eve.
- This is the encryption "circuit": `Alice -- e_alice -- Eve -- e_bob -- Bob`
- Both Alice and Bob use `e` to express the encryption key they use.
- **Thus in conditions where there is no MitM, `e_alice` == `e_bob`**
- Alice wants to verify that there is no MitM, so uses a verification question (and an answer) (like OTR in XMPP):

Q: `Do you have a cat?`

A: `Yes`

*Note: Obviously use strong values for `A`. Don't ask about the **presence** of a cat, but rather cat's **name** (ideally if it's a unique name containing numbers and special characters) :P*

- Alice sends Q to Bob
- Bob sends `hash(e_bob+A)`. `hash` is any safe hashing algorithm, `e_bob` is the encryption key Bob uses, and `A` is the answer, *salt* in this context.
- Alice compares `received == hash(e_alice+A)`. In case this is true, there is no MitM.

---

In this context:

- The hashing algorithm for zero-knowledge-proof
- The encryption keys are a pre-shared (by the key exchange) secret
- The answer is used as salt (while being another pre-shared secret), so Eve can't think: "Oh look, that's a sha1 hash. Let's try to crack it. Oh look it's our encryption key -- that's a no-go"
- Possibly add additional en**coding** like base64 to minimize chance of hashed contents being in wordlists. (`hash(base64(e_bob+A))`)

---

**Question**: Are there any serious vulnerabilities, or would this work for authentication for insecure encrypted channels?

Comment: Don't call the secret a salt. It's not a salt, it should have the properties of a secret key to be secure. For SHA256 for instance, it should have 256 bits (although you could get away with a lot less). You should definitely restrict the amount of connection attempts if you use an *actual* cats name; those are easy to iterate over. If you have a secret with almost enough bits of randomness, use a key strengthening function such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: The base 64 encoding doesn't do anything to avoid the issue described above. Once the attacker knows that encoding is used, then the attacker can simply perform the encoding as well. Encoding schemes in general *do not add security* to any scheme, ever.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Well, the base64 doesn't prevent brute force attack, but it prevents rainbow tables.

Comment: You mean use the key strenghtening like`hash(e+key_strenghtening_algorithm(A))`?

Comment: No, it doesn't protect against rainbow tables, it prevents one specific rainbow table. And you don't need to. If you use ephemeral-ephemeral DH then you'd generate a new key pair and thus a new $e$ every time as well. Now *that* will prevent rainbow tables to occur (I don't think it is possible for the other party to force a specific $e$ by sending a specific & valid public key). And yes, that scheme could work (I'd use a HMAC instead of a hash as fgrieu already indicated though).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Protect against common rainbow tables to be specific, then. And okay, I will look into HMAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [question as it stands now](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/40943/3), nothing prevents Eve to relay `Do you have a cat?` to Bob, get the answer A = `Yes` by testing A for `Yes` or `No` against `hash(e_bob+A)` obtained from Bob, then send `hash(e_alice+A)` to Alice and defeat the protocol.

In a now-gone comment, it was added that we

> should use "strong values" for A; only Q is sent, plain A is never sent.

Notice that then, in order for Alice to perform a check, A must be known to Alice in advance. If this "strong value" (or even the convention to use it the way described) is known to Alice and Bob, but not Eve, then the technique works.

If only the "strong value" is unknown to Eve, it acts as a secret key in an ad-hoc protocol (for something academic we'd want to use this "strong value" as key to HMAC of message `e`)

If the convention is unknown to Eve, that's not cryptography in the modern sense of [Kerckhoffs's second principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle); and that's brittle, and can't be generalized.